# add two vertical lines (rectangle) on right and left side of html page

Tags: css, html

I am new to HTML , CSS and I want to add two vertical lines on the both sides (left and right) of the html page.
A bit of help would be very much appreciated...Thanks very much indeed
Edit: the code has now been added

```
            <!doctype html>
            <html lang="en">

            <head>
            <style>
            #button1{
            width: 300px;
            height: 40px;

            }

            #button2{
            width: 300px;
            height: 40px;
            }

            #link1{
            font-size: 33px;}

            #pic1 {
                 position:fixed;
                left:30%;
                top:30%;
                margin-left:-382px /*half the width*/
                margin-top:-370px /*half the height*/
            }



            </style>

            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="Homepage" content="Starting page for the survey website ">

            <title> Survey HomePage</title>
            </head>

            <body>

            <img src="kingstonunilogo.jpg" alt="uni logo" style="width:180px;height:160px">
            <button type="button home-button" id="button1" >Home</button>
            <button type="button contact-button" id="button2">Contact Us</button>
            <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/" id="link1">LogIn</a>
            <img src="homepagepic.jpg" alt="homepagepic" id="pic1" style="width:400px;height:350px">



            </body> 
            </html>
```

Comment: Sure, we'd like to help. But where is your code you want us to help with?

Comment: it has now been added...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try creating a div container in your body and setting the borders, something along these lines:

```
<body style="width:100%">
//you can set the div-width to 100% too, I'm setting it to 95% so you can see it.//
    <div style="width:95%;border-left:1px solid #000;border-right:1px solid #000;">
        Page contents go here
    </div>
</body>
```

**Preview:** http://jsfiddle.net/pbj4xxh0/

Comment: thanks very much...how do you get them to go all the way down?

Comment: @Hollywood simply by adding more text, or setting the div and body height to 100% (style="height:100%")